# Deferred Rendering Not Working as Expected

Tags: opengl, sdl, lighting, deferred-rendering

I'm fairly experienced with opengl and GLSL. For my engine I wanted to implement deferred lighting, knowing it was not going to be a trivial task. After a few hours I was able to get things mostly working. Here is a screenshot of all the buffers I've rendered:

[image]
The upper left is the normals, the upper right is the albedo, the lower left is the position and the lower right is the final render. (There is only one light being rendered right now.)
I use various shaders to render all the things to a frame buffer. I had previously used a forward rendering lighting shader. To hopefully provide the same results, I used the same data from that vertex shader to render the different buffers. The light source moves and changes based on the position of my camera, unlike my forward renderer. Here is the code for the vertex shaders (the fragment ones just render the pixels they got from the vertex one)

Position shader:

```
varying vec4 pos;
void main(void)
{
    gl_Position =gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix*gl_Vertex;
    pos = gl_ModelViewMatrix*gl_Vertex;
}
```

Normal shader

```
varying vec3 normal;
void main(void)
{
     gl_Position =gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix*gl_Vertex;
    normal = normalize(gl_NormalMatrix*gl_Normal);
}
```

For the albedo I just use opengl's regular shader and just bind textures.

Here is the final light shader which is being rendered as a quad over the screen:

```
uniform sampler2D positionMap;
uniform sampler2D normalMap;
uniform sampler2D albedoMap;
varying vec2 texcoord;
uniform mat4 matrix;
void main()
{
    vec3 position = vec3(texture2D(positionMap,texcoord));
    vec3 normal = vec3(texture2D(normalMap,texcoord));

    vec3 L = normalize(gl_LightSource[0].position.xyz - position);
    float l = length(L)/5.0;
    float att = 1.0/(l*l+l);

    //render sun light
    vec4 diffuselight = max(dot(normal,L), 0.0)*vec4(att,att,att,att);
    diffuselight = clamp(diffuselight, 0.0, 1.0)*2.0;
    vec4 amb = vec4(.2,.2,.2,0);

    vec4 texture = texture2D(albedoMap,texcoord);

    gl_FragColor =  ((diffuselight)+amb)*texture;

}
```

This has a lot of functions that are referenced elsewhere, but I think you can get the general basis from the pictures and the code. This is the main rendering function:

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

//render skybox
glLoadIdentity();
renderSkybox();
//skybox.renderObject();
glLoadIdentity();
renderViewModel();


renderCamera();
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
GLfloat position[] = {-Lighting.x,-Lighting.y,-Lighting.z,1};
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, position);
glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);

glm::mat4 modelView,projection,final;
glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, &modelView[0][0]);
glGetFloatv(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, &projection[0][0]);
final=modelView*projection;

Lighting.setupDepthImage();
glLoadIdentity();

for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); i++)
{
   objects[i].renderObjectForDepth();
}
    Lighting.finishDepthImage();

//render the 3 buffers

//normal buffer
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, Lighting.Normal.frameBuffer);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); i++)
{
  objects[i].renderObjectWithProgram(Lighting.normalShader);
}
//albedo
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, Lighting.Albedo.frameBuffer);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); i++)
{
    objects[i].renderObjectWithProgram(0);
}
//position
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, Lighting.Position.frameBuffer);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); i++)
{
    objects[i].renderObjectWithProgram(Lighting.positionShader);
}
//go back to rendering directly to the screen
 glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);


renderCamera();
glTranslatef(-test.position.x, test.position.y, -test.position.z);
test.updateParticle(1);

//render the buffers for debugging
renderViewModel();
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho(0, 1280, 800, 0, -1, 1);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();

//render the full screen quad for the sun
glUseProgram(Lighting.sunShader);

glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(Lighting.sunShader,"normalMap"),0);
glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(Lighting.sunShader,"albedoMap"),1);
glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(Lighting.sunShader,"positionMap"),2);
glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(Lighting.sunShader, "matrix"), 1, GL_FALSE, &final[0][0]);

glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, Lighting.Normal.texture);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, Lighting.Albedo.texture);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE2);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, Lighting.Position.texture);




glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, Lighting.debugFinal.frameBuffer);
 glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
glVertex2f(0, 0);
glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
glVertex2f(1280, 0);
glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
glVertex2f(1280, 800);
glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
glVertex2f(0, 800);
glEnd();

glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

glUseProgram(0);
//normals
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,Lighting.Normal.texture);
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
glVertex2f(0, 0);
glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
glVertex2f(640, 0);
glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
glVertex2f(640, 400);
glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
glVertex2f(0, 400);
glEnd();
//albedo
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,Lighting.Albedo.texture);
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
glVertex2f(640, 0);
glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
glVertex2f(1280, 0);
glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
glVertex2f(1280, 400);
glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
glVertex2f(640, 400);
glEnd();
//position
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,Lighting.Position.texture);
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
glVertex2f(0, 400);
glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
glVertex2f(640, 400);
glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
glVertex2f(640, 800);
glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
glVertex2f(0, 800);
glEnd();
//final image
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,Lighting.debugFinal.texture);
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
glVertex2f(640, 400);
glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
glVertex2f(1280, 400);
glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
glVertex2f(1280, 800);
glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
glVertex2f(640, 800);
glEnd();
View3D();



SDL_GL_SwapWindow(window);
glLoadIdentity();
```

There are a few unrelated things in here, just ignore them. As you saw, I get the light's position using GLSL's default method. I think that because I am in an orthographic view, something is screwing with the light's position. Could this be the problem, or is there something else, perhaps in the calculation of the normals,etc?

Comment: Where are your `#version` directives?

Comment: @genpfault I've never had any trouble with not having them...

Comment: Look into reconstructing world-space / view-space position from the depth buffer. Storing the position in its own buffer with adequate precision (e.g. 32-bit FP per-component) will eat memory bandwidth like there is no tomorrow. For that matter, define which coordinate space your G-Buffers are stored in clearly somewhere, this may be your entire problem; I prefer world-space buffers for performance in the various post-processing effects I use and most of the big name engines (e.g. Unreal Engine 4, CryTek 3, etc. do the same).

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman right now I'm not concerned with RAM problems. If the precision still wasn't very hight wouldn't it still have a similar result as the straight rendering?

Comment: Yeah, that is why I mentioned coordinate spaces in the second half of the comment. Depending on what you write to the color buffer for your position buffer (which I still say is unnecessary), you could wind up with lights moving relative to the camera or staying in place simply because you mismatched world- vs. view-space. All of your lighting has to be done in the same coordinate space, and when you store the buffers yourself issues that you never had to think about before suddenly pop up for the first time.

Comment: However, another thing jus struck me as odd after glancing at your code again... you normalize a vector, then take its length to use for attenuation. But the length of a normalized vector is always 1, so the attenuation will not work.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman I stop normalizing the normal, thanks. I've never really messed around with this kind of stuff before. I assume that everything is screen-space because it changes as I move the camera. Basted on the code I gave you, can you give me a bit of insight on which one I'm using.

Comment: You actually _do_ want to normalize the light direction vector, but you want to compute its length **before** you normalize it. As for which coordinate space your buffers are in, they are all in view-space (also called eye- or camera-space) if you are writing `pos` and `normal` in your fragment shader. Also, storing the position buffer is not simply a matter of how much RAM it takes, but how much performance it takes to read/write the RAM rather than compute the position from the depth buffer. Computing the position by re-using the depth buffer will always win out on modern hardware.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman If they are all in view space, shouldn't I not have any kind of problems with it? That leads me to thing that the light position being in the orthographic projection is the problem.

Comment: No, projection does not affect anything in view-space. Projection is actually the process that occurs immediately after everything is transformed into view-space, it is used to transform from view-space to clip-space. But all of your lighting here is done in view-space so it will not matter. Incidentally, this _would_ matter if you were reconstructing the position from the depth buffer, as the depth is calculated after projection. These comments are getting really messy, we might need to take this into chat :)

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman according to the opengl FAQ, the light position is changed by the modelview matrix. Since changing the ortho to be a 2D changes the model matrix, doesn't that change the lights position while rendering the lighting pass?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38930/discussion-between-andon-m-coleman-and-bluespud)

Comment: The [deferred] tag appears to be incorrectly applied to this question but I'm not confident enough to remove it. Anybody?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

People will probably not find this useful but I have solved my problem. I was using the regular opengl lights for lighting in the shader. When I set the position I made the w value 1, which would make it a directional light, not a point light, and therefore gave the light moving behavior.

As a side not I changed the position to reconstruct from the depth buffer as well as a few other things to improve the G-buffer.

Comment: Ah, yes. I am surprised I did not think about this. You need to be aware that position vectors always have a 4th component (usually 1.0), so that 4x4 matrix multiplication works properly for operations like translation. Direction vectors can be 3D with the understanding that when multiplied by a 4x4 matrix, w is implicitly 0.0. Which explains perfectly why point lights (positional) have w=1.0, whereas directional lights have w=0.0. Be aware that when you specify a vertex pos. in a VBO using only 3 coordinates, when you use it in a vertex shader as a `vec4` 1.0 is automatically assigned to w.